# Storing progress information in session bean

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

We are running 4 instances of tomcat server in 2 geo-locations with DNS-based load balancer. We are providing some export services which tasks require a lot of time to complete. So the user typically submits a request to one of our servers and that is responsible for whole processing.

[image]

The problem shows up when the user is later requesting for progress information on a randomly chosen instance.

I was thinking about sharing progress information across all instances such as a spring authentication is shared using Redis. I've tried to use spring session bean with aop proxy for sharing progress information, but it seems to be a bad idea. I did some research and debugging that shows the bean is stored in Redis and can be accessed by all instances, but the state is no longer updated. I believe that's because the thread is not able update session information after the original request is return to caller.

Another solution I could think of, is to use our MySQL database for storing such information, but i'm afraid of huge overload caused by continual updating of progress information.

Any ideas to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance,

Michal

Comment: It's not quite clear from your description, but would it be practical to use Spring Session to synchronize the sessions across the containers and then store a key to retrieve progress information in that session?

Comment: spring authentication is shared using Redis? Is that a legit thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of time to complete" exactly? If it is less than session timeout, maybe sticky sessions would simply solve the problem?

Comment: @cichystefan "Lot of time" I mean 5min to 2hours. Sticky session would possibly solve my problem, but we cannot use them because some internal restrictions in our company.

Comment: @SachinVerma I thing this is legit, because spring has built-in support for such thing. I think it is storing that information in memory or some internal redis by default anyway. This [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/guides/security.html) to spring documentation shows how the security session could be implemented.

Comment: @chrylis That's what I'm trying to do. It works great when I store something to the session FE.: in controller within one request. This information is later accessible by all instances. The problem is in fact updating a session without the session inside a thread running background on server. So that storing a key is a good idea, but there is still problem with the progress data. Maybe I will store them to redis manually with that key you've suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've finally resolved my issue. I was thinking hard about persisting a progress information in session, that was not available when processing an asynchronous task, and I've completely overlooked the fact it is not a good idea:-)

My new solution is as simple as it could be. The unique task id is generated when user requests for task processing and returned to client. Progress information is continuously updated in redis under defined task key, so that the task id could be later used when client is requesting a task state. There is no need for using session because the redis instances are synchronized by replication itself.

[image: redis-cli preview]

Thanks everyone for comments!

Regards,

Michal